Installation of C++ libraries 'Boost' and 'BLAS' for Python project fail on Windows
I'm working on a Python project. After cloning a remote git repository I followed the instructions in the README file, executing multiple pip install commands in my VSCode PowerShell terminal to set up the project correctly. However the last step was to run the following command sudo apt install cmake libboost-all-dev libblas-dev to install the dependencies that can not be installed via pip install.
Since I am working on Windows I used the Chocolatey package manager changing the command to choco install cmake libboost-all-dev libblas-dev. CMake was found and installed successfully, however it fails to find the Boost library and the BLAS library. I found out that the commands libboost-all-dev and libblas-dev are supposed to install all the corresponding libraries of Boost and BLAS on Ubuntu, however I couldn't find an alternative for Windows.
So how do I install Boost and BLAS on Windows and embed them in my Python project? If this is important: The project runs in an virtual environment (but I have already set this up previously and it can be activated without any problems).
Furthermore the authors of the README file noted, that their system was only tested on Ubuntu and MacOS, there was no mention about Windows.
Running choco install cmake libboost-all-dev libblas-dev using Chocolatey as a package manager only installed CMake, but it fails to install Boost and BLAS, because they can't be found. I also found out that the 'Scoop' package manager seems to be able to find Boost, but not BLAS. So it wouldn't really solve my problem.

Alas, I ditched Windows, so I can’t play with it directly, but chances are you need to configure your CMake project(s) to find the libraries directly. There are too many ways to store libraries on Windows to give an easy answer.

@Dúthomhas CMake is really not the problem here. As already mentioned, it was found by the Chocolatey package manager and installed successfully. The problem is that it can't find Boost and BLAS. The shell command I posted only works on Linux, but I couldn't find an alternative for Windows.
